# Trying to call a layout class within a screen layout - kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Essentially, I have multiple screens, being controlled by the screen manager (primarily for logins), however on the main screen, I have it broken up with a header, nav bar, and a section for the body. In the body section is where I want to be able to call different layouts that I have classes for, and add and remove these as buttons on the nav bar are pressed.

Im using kivy to control all aspects of the gui, but am rather new to it. At the moment I have:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<MainMenu>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.235, 0.271, 0.302, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            rows: 4
            Label:
                size_hint: 1,0.12
                text: "ProductName"
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                font_size: 32
                color: [0.114,0.18,0.224,1]
                
            StackLayout:
                size_hint: 1,0.10
                orientation: 'lr-tb'
                #Purchase Order System
                Button:
                    id: butpos
                    text: "Purchase Order"
                    size_hint: 0.166,1
                    on_press: spaceholder.add_widget(pos)
                #Asset Assignment System
                Button:
                    id: butaas
                    text: "Asset Assignment"
                    size_hint: 0.166,1
                #Review and Revise System
                Button:
                    id: butrrs
                    text: "Review"
                    size_hint: 0.166,1
                #Administrative System
                Button:
                    id: butadm
                    text: "Administration"
                    size_hint: 0.166,1
                #Analytics and Reporting System
                Button:
                    id: butars
                    text: "Analytics"
                    size_hint: 0.166,1
                #Placeholder, possibly documentation
                Button:
                    id: butbut
                    text: "Placeholder"
                    size_hint: 0.166,1
                    
            Label:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0.259, 0.643, 0.937, 1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                size_hint: 1,0.005
                
            Widget:
                id: spaceholder

<PurchaseOrder>
    id: pos
    orientation: 'lr-tb'
    #Asset Details
    Label:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: "Asset Requirements"
            Label:
                text: "Asset1: "
            TextInput:
                id: as1count
            Label:
                text: "Asset2: "
            TextInput:
                id: as2count
                
''')
```

```
class MainMenu(Screen):
    pass
class PurchaseOrder(StackLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainMenu(name='mainmenu'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

PurchaseOrder is a class that Id like to be added or removed, much like classes I intend to set up for the other navigation options. Ive tried a number of methods, but I think im missing something. Im either being thrown with 'pos' is not defined, or that 'spaceholder' has wrong attributes when ive tried different combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make that work by modifying the `Purchase Order` `Button`:

```
on_press: spaceholder.add_widget(Factory.PurchaseOrder())
```

That requires an addition to your `kv` to import `Factory`:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
```

I would recommend using a `Layout` for your `spaceholder` to take advantage of their sizing and positioning capabilities. For example, using an `AnchorLayout` automatically centers its child (but is limited to a single child). Like this:

```
        AnchorLayout:
            id: spaceholder
```